# Syntax error when using TRIM() in PDO MySQL SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I tried to use TRIM() in a PDO SELECT query and got a syntax error message as "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;". What should I do to correct this error?

DB:

```
tblrecord (firstname, lastname, score)
```

PHP:

```
$firstname = trim('Mary');

$lastname = trim('Lamb');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblrecord WHERE TRIM(firstname) AS firstname = ? AND TRIM(lastname) AS lastname = ?";

$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute( array($firstname, $lastname) );
```

Comment: `AS` should be on the `SELECT` column/table names, not on your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use alias on the `WHERE`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblrecord WHERE TRIM(firstname) = ? AND TRIM(lastname) = ?";
```